# Image position not consistent across different browsers

Tags: html, css, position

CSS/HTML Newbie. I have a logo I'm trying position on a page. On Firefox, IE and Chrome on my desktop it appears in the position i want. On my MBPr it's in a different position (Chrome and Safari both display it in the same position. Thanks for your help.

I found the `#fsbg` trick [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

CSS

```
#fsbg {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -100;
  left: 0px; top: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1040px;
}

#logo {
  position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  right:0;
  top:46px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}

#body { font-family: Arial; }
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <img src="image.jpg" name="fsbg" width="2880" height="1913" id="fsbg">
  <div id="logo"> 
    <img src="image.jpg" width="201" height="103">
  </div>
</body
```

This is what it should look like (the 'gonenomadic' logo) http://i40.tinypic.com/2qkm3qc.jpg

In safari and chrome on my MBPr its a bit lower.

Comment: what you want to reach?

Comment: Please explain why what you have already isn't working as you expect.

Comment: I'm trying to position an image but its appearing in a different position in safari and chrome on my Macbook pro to my Windows desktop.

Comment: "It's a bit lower" <- Is that a problem?

Comment: thanks for replying, yes (that's why im asking for help?)

Comment: How do you set the vertical and horizontal lines behind the logo? Is that maybe not rendering the same, due to the different height of the browser viewports?

Comment: You are using a `reset.css`. Zero out all properties that could affect your image and build css from baseline

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos thats the background image. i created the lines on the background image in photoshop

Comment: @gwillie I'm curious: How do you know the OP is using a reset.css ?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos oops, it was meant to read `Are you using...`

Comment: @gwillie Hi, no i'm not using a css reset

Comment: @Shoegazer...anything to do with your image's position (for that fact, every element) should be reset to some baseline, so no matter what browser it is viewed in, the baseline css styles are applied first. Search google for 'reset.css' or similar. I'm an advocate of css resets :)

Comment: @gwillie tried using a css reset (normalize.css) still have the same problem, ive set up a test site so you can take a look gonenomadictest.co.nf

Comment: @Shoegazer without a `MBPr` at hand, all I can say is...you'll need a 'Mac Book' Professional to help. If the css reset didn't help, and inspector reports the same settings, then maybe it's an iOS version (i doubt, but it's apple, and they're no better than microsoft any more) problem. Beyond that, your link `gonenomadictest.co.nf` shows fine and dandy on debian 6 chrome 19 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You want a scalable background? You could use pure CSS

```
body {
    background: url(image.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This works on modern browsers. For use on IE8 and lower you can use backgroundsize.htc
https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Comment: thanks for replying. No not a background, i'm just trying to position the 'gonenomadic' logo i posted a screenshot of, its just a png. In one browser it looks fine and in other its slightly lower.